# cannot copy object in forEach of mixed types to object of same type typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following type:

```
export interface PopupProps {
  cornerRadius?: number;
  debugMode?: boolean;
  eventOff?: keyof HTMLElementEventMap;
  eventOn?: keyof HTMLElementEventMap;
  //and so on
}
```

And the following code that I modified in my class from a similar answer I was referred to by my previous version of this question

```
keysOf<T extends Object>(obj: T): Array<keyof T> {
  return Array.from(Object.keys(obj)) as any;
}


keysOf<T extends Object>(obj: T): Array<keyof T> {
  return Array.from(Object.keys(obj)) as any;
}

mergeConfig(config: PopupProps, overrides: PopupProps) : PopupProps {
  const result: PopupProps = {}

   this.keysOf(config).forEach((key) => {
     let value = config[key];
     const newValue = overrides[key]
     if (typeof value !== "undefined") {
       value = newValue;
     }
     result[key] = value;
   });

  return result;
}
```

I have to post a new question because the answer I was referred to doesn't explain why result[key] can't be assigned a value, and I can't write code in a comment

Comment: To safely iterate expected keys in objects, an explicit list of keys must be available. Here's a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) example based on the code you provided: https://tsplay.dev/wedKVW